# Working of concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor max workers when scaling up the application

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, threadpoolexecutor

I am new to Python programming. Most of my code is using the `asyncio`, as I am making the IO calls to the database, though in certain cases I am using the non async methods which are long running like few Pandas framework calls to the database, therefore to avoid the blocking call which restricts scalability, I am using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to execute the blocking method as follows:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
      values = executor.map(func, data)
```

The `func` above is supplied the data collection which is at max of length 2, basically requiring no more than 2 threads, but when multiple users come in and application needs to scale, at that time, what shall be ideal `max_workers` value:

1. Shall it be required by each user, which is 2
2. Shall it be max possible value, which as mentioned on the link - https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

> Changed in version 3.8: Default value of max_workers is changed to min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4). This default value preserves at least 5 workers for I/O bound tasks. It utilizes at most 32 CPU cores for CPU bound tasks which release the GIL. And it avoids using very large resources implicitly on many-core machines.

3. Shall I not mention it at all and it can be spawned as per requirement

Main point remains, if 10 users start doing the same operation do they end up using the same `ThreadPoolExecutor`(shared) or do they end up getting the different executor as this is not shared object. I wanted to ensure that when scaled up application doesn't suffer due to incorrect design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) from the async code you should use `asyncio` [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) function, otherwise it will block the main event loop.

If the extra workload is CPU bound then you should also use [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) instead.

**Example from Python docs:**

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

def cpu_bound():
    # CPU-bound operations will block the event loop:
    # in general it is preferable to run them in a
    # process pool.
    return sum(i * i for i in range(10 ** 7))

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, cpu_bound)
        print('custom process pool', result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

When it comes to `max_workers`, the default value is usually fine:

- `ThreadPoolExecutor`: `min(32, (os.cpu_count() or 1) + 4)`
- `ProcessPoolExecutor`: `os.cpu_count() or 1`

It depends on your workload (CPU vs. I/O bound) but for CPU bound tasks there is no point to set this to a number greater than available CPUs as it may actually degrade the performance due to context switching etc.

Both executors are using queues to enqueue and schedule task on available threads/processes.

**Update: Thu 25 Mar 15:17:51 UTC 2021**

The `asyncio` event loop is single threaded so you'll see the issue when you schedule other coroutines at the same time. As you can see the `none-blocking` task was blocked for 10s by the `blocking executor`:

```
$ python test.py
START none-blocking executor: (scheduled: 5.0s)
START none-blocking: (scheduled: 1.0s)
START blocking executor: (scheduled: 10.0s)
END none-blocking executor: (elapsed: 5.0s)
END blocking executor: (elapsed: 10.0s)
END none-blocking: (elapsed: 10.0s)
```

If you run this a few times and the `blocking executor` will start first, `none-blocking` task won't be even started before the `blocking executor` will end:

```
$ python test.py
START none-blocking executor: (scheduled: 5.0s)
START blocking executor: (scheduled: 10.0s)
END none-blocking executor: (elapsed: 5.0s)
END blocking executor: (elapsed: 10.0s)
START none-blocking: (scheduled: 1.0s)
END none-blocking: (elapsed: 1.0s)
```

When you comment out the `blocking executor` you can see that all calls are asynchronous now:

```
$ python test.py
START none-blocking executor: (scheduled: 5.0s)
START none-blocking: (scheduled: 1.0s)
END none-blocking: (elapsed: 1.0s)
END none-blocking executor: (elapsed: 5.0s)
```

The key takeaway is that once you start writing asynchronous code you can't mix it with synchronous calls.

**test.py:**

```
import asyncio
import time

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def blocking(msg, t):
    t1 = time.perf_counter()

    print(f"START {msg}: (scheduled: {t}s)")
    time.sleep(t)
    print(f"END {msg}: (elapsed: {time.perf_counter() - t1:.1f}s)")


async def task1(msg, t):
    t1 = time.perf_counter()

    print(f"START {msg}: (scheduled: {t}s)")
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    print(f"END {msg}: (elapsed: {time.perf_counter() - t1:.1f}s)")


async def task2(msg, t):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future = executor.submit(blocking, msg, t)
        future.result()


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    aws = [
        task1("none-blocking", 1.0),
        loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking, "none-blocking executor", 5.0),
        task2("blocking executor", 10.0),
    ]

    for coro in asyncio.as_completed(aws):
        await coro


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Does this mean in the Async code following two calls are exactly same `cpu_bound()` or running the same using `Thread Pool Executor`, map or submit, both are the blocking calls, but then they shall behave the same way in the non async code. 
My understanding is using thread executor spawns a new thread to free up the main GIL thread, otherwise it will remain blocking in all cases

Comment: Probably the benefit of running it in `run_in_executor` is to use the event loop prepared for async processing, thus queuing up operations and increase the system scalability

Comment: @MrinalKamboj by default `run_in_executor` will use `ThreadPoolExecutor`, see the full example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). As I mentioned, it depends how you call `ThreadPoolExecutor`, if that's from the async code then If you don't run it in the `run_in_executor`, no other coroutine will be able to run while executor is running.

Comment: what you are saying is following code is not correct, https://ideone.com/lDVLFh, but I am not able to find an issue while running it, Nontheless thanks for heloing out, let me check out various options / docs available

Comment: @MrinalKamboj see my update to your comment.

Comment: Appreciate all the help, thank you will try this tomorrow and update the details

Comment: Thank you for such a brilliant explanation